# Deploying shiny app not displaying ggvis graph

Tags: r, shiny, ggvis

I'm trying to deploy a shiny app that I've created. It displays perfectly locally but it doesn't not display correctly when deploying it. I have the following ui and server scripts:

```
# ui.R
library("shiny")
library("ggvis")
shinyUI(fluidPage(
titlePanel("Barcelona Wine Menu"),

sidebarLayout(
sidebarPanel(
  helpText("Display information about the selected variable"),

  selectInput("var", 
              label = "Choose a variable to display",
              choices = c("mpc", "mpv"),                 
              selected = "mpc")
),

mainPanel(
  ggvisOutput("meanpc")


)
)
))
# server.R
library("shiny")
library("ggvis")
shinyServer(
function(input, output) {
mpc <- mean.price.country
mpv <- mean.price.vintage


selection <- reactive({ifelse (input$var=="mpc", return(mpc), return(mpv))})

observe({
  selection() %>%
    ggvis(~V1, ~V2) %>%
    layer_bars() %>%
    bind_shiny("meanpc" )
})})
```

[image: local]

[image: deploy]

When I deploy, I see the second picture which doesn't display the data like it does when I run it locally. I haven't been able to find similar issues as the majority are errors. Does anyone know why this isn't deploying properly? I've read through the shinyapp.io documentation and followed those steps but without avail. Thank you.

Comment: Try deploying a static version with no data (all fake data). If that works you know it is the data reading that is failing (that is a common problem on shiny.io - note you have no control of system specific variables). OTOH, if it still fails you can continue by eliminating features and code incrementally until you find the cause. That is how I would debug it.

Comment: The app greyed out, this indicates an error terminated the session.  Please post the log.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is the first troubleshooting step suggested by Mike Wise. The data that I was using was stored "locally" within my environment. When I published this to Shiny, it didn't recognize the data. All I did was create an Excel sheet in the working directory folder and then imported that data into the function I wrote above.